# Back stack fragment is displayed on top current fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am using fragments in my app. When I press back button to go the previous fragment, the fragment is displayed on top of the current fragment.

```
fragManager.beginTransaction().addToBackStack("myList").replace(R.id.placeHolderFrag, new Search_Frag()).commit();
```

How can I solve this problem?